# Password char doesnt work when i try to make my custom TextBox

Tags: c#, class, passwords, controls, custom-controls

I made a custom `TextBox` so that I can have it bordered, that works fine...
The problem is that I want to set `PasswordChar` to `*`, and that doesn't work
Here is my code:

```
public  class TextBoxEx : TextBox
{
    // The TextBox
    private TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

    // Border color of the textbox
    private Color borderColor = Color.Gray;

    // Ctor
    public TextBoxEx()
    {
        this.PasswordChar ='*';
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(TextBoxEx_Paint);
        this.Resize += new EventHandler(TextBoxEx_Resize);
        textBox.Multiline = true;
        textBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        this.Controls.Add(textBox);
        this.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;

        InvalidateSize();
    }

    // Exposed properties of the textbox
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return textBox.Text; }
        set { textBox.Text = value; }
    }
    // ... Expose other properties you need...

    // The border color property
    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return borderColor; }
        set { borderColor = value; Invalidate(); }
    }

    // Expose the Click event for the texbox
    public event EventHandler TextBoxClick
    {
        add { textBox.Click += value; }
        remove { textBox.Click -= value; }
    }
    // ... Expose other events you need...

    private void TextBoxEx_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InvalidateSize();
    }
    private void TextBoxEx_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle, borderColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }
    private void InvalidateSize()
    {
        textBox.Size = new Size(this.Width - 2, this.Height - 2);
        textBox.Location = new Point(1, 1);
    }
}
```

Generally when I try to set the properties of custom control by default it doesn't work, for example if I set

```
this.ReadOnly=true;
```

This won't work either. So the problem isn't in `PasswordChar` itself.

Anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab at this:

```
private TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

...

this.Controls.Add(textBox);
```

The above seems to be the problem. It seems your shadow textbox is actually what's displaying.

If you need shadow properties in the back ground (and without really knowing your goal), probably just best creating the properties you need.

Comment: When i remove it it works, but i dont understand why...I will accept your answer

Comment: @FloRida `this.Controls.Add(textBox);` it is displaying first and foremost, its in front of the actual custom textbox

Comment: @Flo Rida  You should also consider to re-design your class, taking into considration what has been pointed out in the other answer. The `TextBoxEx_Resize` event, first of all. Where you also set `Location = new Point(1, 1);`. Sure about that?

Answer (score 4):

Since the class is itself inheriting the `TextBox` class, you don't need to create an inner textbox.

With that in mind, you can take out your declaration of `private TextBox textBox`, and replace references to this member with `this`, since `this` is a `TextBox` descendant.

In the constructor, you will also remove `this.Controls.Add(textBox);` since there is no longer an inner control to add.

The overridden `Text` property can also be removed, as it doesn't add functionality to the `TextBox` definition.

The `InvalidateSize` method will need to be reworked, since adjusting the `Size` member triggers the `TextBoxEx_Resize` handler method, which calls the `InvalidateSize` method again, eventually causing a `StackOverflowException`.

One last thing, and an important one. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar(VS.80).aspx)...

> If the [Multiline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.multiline(v=vs.80).aspx) property is set to true, setting the PasswordChar property has no visual effect. When the PasswordChar property is set to true, cut, copy, and paste actions in the control using the keyboard cannot be performed, regardless of whether the Multiline property is set to true or false.

Meaning the textbox PasswordCharacter will not display if the textbox is Multiline